# killing multiple processes listed in a file

Tags: shell-script, process

I'm trying to build a script where it will verify, from a file, if the listed processes are running and if they are, they should be killed.

this file contains similar list to:

```
process01:0
process02:0
process03:0
process04:0
process05:0
```

**NOTE**: some of these processes are running in double, so there are different 2 or 3 for one of these listed processes

Example:

```
user01@qhost0001:/home/user01>ps x
   PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  3514 pts/2    S+     0:00 vim test_script.sh
  3844 pts/1    R+     0:00 ps x
 87844 pts/0    S+     0:00 -bash
100947 ?        S      0:00 sshd: user01@pts/1
100948 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -bash
101434 ?        S      0:00 sshd: user01@pts/2
101435 pts/2    Ss     0:00 -bash
127678 ?        S      0:00 process05 -c process05.cf
127869 ?        S      0:00 process01 -c process01.cf
127872 ?        S      0:00 process01 -c process01.cf
127879 ?        S      0:00 process03 -c process03.cf
127890 ?        S      0:00 process03 -c process03.cf
127904 ?        S      0:00 process03 -c process03.cf
128389 ?        S      0:00 process04 -c process04.cf
```

The script so far I built:

```
#!/bin/bash

proc_name=$(awk -F':' '{ print $1 }' /app/config/process_failures.cf)
PID=$(ps -ef | grep "$proc_name" | grep -v grep | grep -v PID | awk '{print $2}')

test() {
for p in $proc_name
do
  ps -ux | grep $p > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Process $p is runnning."
        echo "Killing the processes"
        pgrep -f $p | xargs kill -9
        else
                echo "Process $p not running."
        fi

done
}

main() {

echo $PID
#test
}

main
```

When I execute to see what returns the echo it returns much more processes than in the file list.
It shows me all the processes running in the host.
If I change to "ps -ux" it shows me all the processes the user is executing but it shows other processes like the the command inside the variable.

So I'm not getting where i getting wrong. Can someone help me clarify where I'm wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that kill / killall do not necessarily terminate processes - options are available to use killall to suspend / resume / etc  processes

Comment: yes, killall alone only sends signal 15

Comment: Not so - `killall` can send **HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM STKFLT
CHLD CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU URG XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH POLL PWR SYS**

Answer (score 1):

So I did with the help of @White Owl I came with the following solution.
I did change the usage from the process list file as I found out there will be no new processes in near future. So I created directly in the script the array of processes.

```
#!/bin/bash

processes=("main_mon" "sql_feed" "sql_intra" "sql_select" "topc" "iact" "isca" "iann" "dv2sql_so" "dv2sql_sorpc" "dv2sql_careo" "slamm" "slamm_mon" "dv2sql_socnt" "mmmtp" "ebus")

check_and_kill() {
for p in ${processes[@]};
do
  ps -ux | grep $p > /dev/null

if [ $? -ge 1 ]; then
        echo "Process $p is runnning."
        echo "Killing the processes"
        killall -s 9 -r $p -v
        else
                echo "No $p process is running."
        fi

done
}

main() {
check_and_kill
}

main
```

This was the solution I found.
Thank you

PS: As a side joke, it seems my relationship with awk or sed will be like Tom and Jerry

Answer (score 0):

If you defining the process to kill by its name - then you should look at the standard tool `killall`.

So to kill all processXX you will do something like

```
killall -r "process[:digit:][:digit:]" --verbose
```

Comment: true, but the not all processes have the same name or a similar partial name. the list processes are just an example.

Comment: ```for pat in $(cat list-of-patterns); do killall -r $pat -v; done```

Comment: thanks, that gave me the tip I needed. Also I gave up on using the file with the list of processes as reference and created an array directly in the script.